# PowerPivot Calculated Field calculating to nearest 10p

Tags: excel, database, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have imported a `dataset` into PowerPivot. This `dataset` includes the following `columns`

- `Month` which is formatted as Date January 2018
- `Name` which is a standard text field
- `Height` which is formatted as a decimal number
- `Length` also formatted as decimal number
- `Type` again a decimal number
- `Measure` which finally is a decimal number
- `Price` which is formatted as Currency (UK) to 2 decimal places.

From this in the dataset I have created 3 columns which then pull through the `number of sales` which is a whole number. Using this I have calculated a `total price` for each line which is `Simple Price` * `Sales` which is formatted as Currency and pulls through the correct number and a `Total Measure` which is `Measure` * `Sales` and again pulls through the correct number.

From here I have then used the `calculation area` to work out a `Measure Per Thousand:=SUM([Total Price])/SUM([Total Measure])*1000` This gives me a result in the area of £33.70 however should be £33.67. When broken down in the Pivot by Name all of these Measures Per Thousands are rounding to the nearest 10p.

Can someone please help me stop this rounding from occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the culprit here is that your `[Total Price]` is formatted as a currency, which is a fixed decimal type that truncates values past 4 decimal places.

When you do the division, the result is coerced to be a currency type that truncates after 4 decimal places and then you multiply by 1000, which leaves only 1 decimal place of accuracy.

I would suggest using a different data type for the `[Total Price]` or if you want to keep that, then do your multiplication before the division. E.g.

```
Measure Per Thousand:= (1000*SUM([Total Price]))/SUM([Total Measure])
```

---

Reference: Microsoft's documentation on [Data types in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-types)

Comment: Indeed you are correct, makes sense. The workaround failed however thankfully changing the Dataset to decimals has resolved so no longer truncating to 4 decimals.